# nHibernate <one-to-one> mapping

Tags: nhibernate

Please help me out

I am trying to do this but nHibernate not allowing can any one help me out how to do this?

Comment: How do you want it mapped? Both classes in the same (shared) table - or two differnet tables? If two tables - should both have identitiers or is one dependant on the other?

Answer (score 0):

Is it truly one-to-one in your data model is it one-to-one in your domain model?
I doubt you have two tables with same PK so you would not use one-to-one.

[How to map it? HasOne x References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783622/how-to-map-it-hasone-x-references/2803860#2803860)